# Android 6.0 how to solve mediarecorder audio video out of sync?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, mediarecorder

As title. Are there any sample code to solve Android 6.0 mediarecorder audio video recording out of sync problem? Here is my code:

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/test.mp4");
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);

WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int rotation = window.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Comment: some suggestions: `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER` is a better audio source for video recording, and try other encoders and formats to see if the sync problem is caused by a specific combination of them

Comment: I have already tried many combination nut still have out of sync problem.

Comment: The mp4 play from audio first and then video.